# Why heterogeneous comparison lookup is not implemented for `at` and `operator []`?

Tags: c++, c++14

Since C++14 (N3657) member function templates `find`, `count`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, and `equal_range` of associative containers support heterogeneous comparison lookup but `at` and `operator[]` don't have those equivalent member function templates. Why is that so ?

Example :

```
std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>> m;
// ...
auto it = m.find("foo"); // does not construct an std::string
auto& v = m.at("foo"); // construct an std::string
```

Comment: They probably forgot.

Comment: The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf) only mentions the functions you list and doesn't list any reason to exclude the others (not sure there would be one). You could just email Joaquin and tell him to fix it.

Comment: `[]` is tricky because it can insert, and there's no guarantee that the thing being looked up can be used to construct a `key_type`.

Comment: @T.C.: currently to use `[]` you need to be able to create a `key_type` from what you pass... so what is the problem of creating it **only** if insert is required and not creating it if a compatible comparison is available and element is already present?

Comment: @6502 So in other words your "heterogeneous" [] only accepts types convertible to `key_type`? That's not very heterogenous. And you also need to impose a new requirement that the thing converted to `key_type` compares the same way as before.

Comment: @T.C.: the point is dead simple... if you can avoid doing the pointless creation of a `key_type` temporary then just don't create it. The problem that the comparison could be semantically different is also present with other cases... or you think it's a feature that `container.find(x)` could use a different semantic than `container[x]` for the comparisons? For the question the only possibilities i can think to are 1) they forgot, 2) template machinery is too weak to handle it. I think 1 is the case (template machinery is indeed horribly weak, but this should still be in reach).

Comment: @6502 you can't "avoid" creation of a `key_type` instance if the key (an argument to `operator[]`) is not in a map. And while `key_type` and `T` might be comparable, there is no requirement that `key_type` is constructible from `T`

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki So in all cases (x in the map or not), if you use operator[x] with key_type not constructible from T it should fail at compile time like it does today if you put some trash inside [].

Comment: @Nicolas `key_type{} < T{}` is not guaranteed to be the same as `key_type{} < key_type{T{}}`

Comment: I presume because few people actually use `at` so it slipped their mind.  `[]` is tricky, as noted above, so deferring it until after a first implementation seems reasonable.  Neither are high-performance operations on a `map`.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The real problem begins with the definition of the container type when the user choose to use the "diamond comparator" `std::map<std::string, int, std::less<>>` . All kind of funky semantic problem could happen then. For example `m.find(x)->first != key_type{x}`. So the user should pay attention to this anyway. The problem just gets worse with `operator[]` since it would potentially mutate the container in a funky way. I thought (beside the tricky implementation) it could explain why they "forgot" about `[]` (and `at` ...) but I couldn't find any information about this issue.

Comment: @Nicolas still, I prefer a scenario where `operator[](x) != find(x)` and internal ordering *is not* broken, to a scenario where `operator[](x) != find(x)` and internal ordering *is silently* broken

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: This is what OP is asking for `operator[]`: if `T` can be compared with `key_type` then do the search using that. If not found (and we're not in the `const` case) create the element by converting `T` to `key_type`. When `T`→`key_type` is not possible then `operator[]` should just not compile if non-const (like happens now, btw). If you can convert `T` to `key_type` but not compare with it then just convert it immediately (like now). You can of course create funky cases like `key_type` being present after converting `T` (but not before). Or compute `<` using `rand()`. So?

Comment: @6502 and if `key_type` is constructible from `T` and `T{}` doesn't exist, then `key_type{T{}}` should be inserted to a binary search tree in place where `T{}` should be? then, you perform `find(T{})`, does it find `key_type{T{}}` that you have just inserted (not to mention that internal ordering is already broken anyway)?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: of course for `T x` and `key_type y` it should be required to have `x < y` if and only if `key_type(x) < y` and `y < x` iff `y < key_type(x)`. If that is not valid then of course mixing the comparison is nonsense (but it's nonsense to use the comparison for `find` too as the algorithms already require ordering properties for `operator<`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no logical reasons in principle for it. For example for `operator[]` a reasonable semantic could be

- If the passed value is comparable with `key_type` do the search using it and convert to `key_type` only if needed (i.e. if the element is not found and the container is neither const nor accessed using a const reference).
- If in the case before the passed type is not convertible to `key_type` the use of `operator[]` should just not compile (like it happens now)
- If the passed type cannot be compared with `key_type` but can be converted to `key_type` then a temporary should be created immediately to do the search and possibly the insertion (like it's now).

Of course there should be a requirement to have `x < y` for a `T` element `x` and a `key_type` element `y` **if and only if** `key_type(x) < y` because otherwise semantic would be nonsense (like it would be nonsense for example to have `operator<` to return a value based on a random source).

Unfortunately C++ template machinery is at the same time extremely complex and extremely weak and implementing the conversion to `key_type` for `operator[]` only when really necessary is probably more complex than it seems.

This machinery is however what the C++ community decided to condemn itself to use for metaprogramming and until someone manages out to get a decent implementation using only that, this reasonable requirement is probably not going to be in the standard (in the past it happened that the standard mandated things that were fuzzily defined and/or basically impossible to implement like template export, and it wasn't funny).

Comment: `map::operator[](key_type)` is never `const`

Comment: I don't think your third bullet point is consistent with the other lookup functions. The user can easily create a temporary themselves, if that's necessary. But it might be required for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @dyp: that's a tradeoff of usability. In the past even `operator==` between an `std::string` and a `const char *` created a temporary, and that (despite inefficient) was convenient because string literals are not std::string objects and users wanted to write `x == "foo"`. The standard solution of providing comparisons with `const char *` too is of course better...

Comment: Well if I'm using a transparent comparator, then I'd like to know when the implementation creates a temporary internally. This can catch performance bugs, where I've intended to provide comparison for the type, but e.g. failed to add a `const` in the comparison operator/function. If the comparison doesn't work but an implicit conversion to the key type does, I think something must be wrong. Typically, the comparison itself allows implicit conversion by taking either by value, or by const-ref.

Comment: @dyp: C++ is a complex language and it's difficult to write a standard for such a beast correctly, let alone efficiently. One of the early writings for example was **mandating three temporary copies** of the key for every `std::map::operator[]` access (even if the element was already present) simply because provided a bad implementation as description of the semantic (luckily enough no implementation AFAIK ever followed the standard on that). Note however that a C++ implementation that makes 100 copies for all pairs of keys tested would be still compliant.

Comment: I have implemented a proof of concept of this [here](https://ideone.com/jJV52M) . The semantic of the `operator[]` is implemented by the `map_get` free function. Feel free to comment or fork